# Can the Spark warning "CSV header does not conform to the schema" be changed to a fault, through the configuration, and stop the current operation?

Tags: csv, apache-spark

This *Spark* warning is very convenient, at the times we switch from 2022 to 2023 with a new csv file.
It notices that we aren't matching anymore. This warning explained me things and saved me tens of times already.

```
WARN CSVDataSource: CSV header does not conform to the schema.
Header: VendorID, passenger_count, trip_distance, RatecodeID, ...
Schema: VendorID, store_and_fwd_flag, RatecodeID, PULocationID, ...
```

Is there a way, through *Spark* configuration, to ask it to stop the current operation as a faulty one, instead of only emitting a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25669) i think you can do that by adding

```
spark.read.option("enforceSchema", false)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've checked, and it's doing exactly what's expected. I even read on _Spark_ documentation that's this is a good practice: "_Though the default value [of enforceSchema] is true, it is recommended to disable the enforceSchema option to avoid incorrect results_."